# Calculating multiple columns from one column with summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
df <- data.frame(label = c(rep("ABC", 5), rep("CDE", 5), rep("FGH", 5)), x = runif(15, 0, 100))

df %>% group_by(label) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), list(lessthan_10 = ~sum(. < 10), lessthan_20 = ~sum(. < 20), lessthan_30 = ~sum(. < 20), lessthan_40 = ~sum(. < 40))))
```

In this case, I'm calculating 4 different columns in the summary (counting the entries less than 10, less than 20, less than 30, and less than 40). In reality, I would like to calculate 100 different columns using a custom function that takes in x and 100 different parameters. Is there a way to do this using a loop or a list without writing out every single column I want to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map_dfc`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(label) %>% 
  summarise(map_dfc(seq(10, 40, 10), ~ tibble("x_lessthan_{.x}" := sum(x < .x))))
```

```r
  label x_lessthan_10 x_lessthan_20 x_lessthan_30 x_lessthan_40
  <chr>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>
1 ABC               0             3             3             3
2 CDE               0             2             3             4
3 FGH               1             2             3             3
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there's a way to specify the numerical formatting of .x in the column names? E.g., if the parameter is one million then I get "x_lessthan_1e+06" as the column name, when I would prefer it to be "x_lessthan_1000000".

Comment: I have no special solution for this, but what I usually do when I have this problem is that I set off the scientific notation by doing `options(scipen = 999)`. It should work after setting that up.

Answer (score 0):

**1) dplyr/tidyr** Using the input in the Note at the end, for each label create 4 rows that each contains a list with the x values and and one of 10, 20, 30, 40.  Then for each such row create the corresponding sum and sum name and finally convert that to wide form.

Change the `paste0` to whatever formatting you want, e.g. `sprintf("Less_than_%d", s)` will force it not to use e notation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  summarize(x = list(x), s = seq(10, 40, 10)) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(value = sum(x < s), name = paste0("Less_than_", s)) %>%
  pivot_wider(label)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  label Less_than_10 Less_than_20 Less_than_30 Less_than_40
  <chr>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
1 ABC              0            0            1            1
2 CDE              1            1            1            1
3 FGH              0            1            1            1
```

**2) Base R**  To get a base only solution use `outer` on `s` and `label` defined as shown.

```
s <- seq(10, 40, 10)
names(s) <- paste("Less_than_", s)

label <- unique(df$label)

f <- function(g, s) sum(subset(df, label == g)$x < s)
data.frame(label, outer(label, s, Vectorize(f)))
```

### Note

To make the definition of `df` reproducible we add a `set.seed` .

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(label = c(rep("ABC", 5), rep("CDE", 5), rep("FGH", 5)), 
                 x = runif(15, 0, 100))
```

giving:

```
> df
   label        x
1    ABC 28.75775
2    ABC 78.83051
3    ABC 40.89769
4    ABC 88.30174
5    ABC 94.04673
6    CDE  4.55565
7    CDE 52.81055
8    CDE 89.24190
9    CDE 55.14350
10   CDE 45.66147
11   FGH 95.68333
12   FGH 45.33342
13   FGH 67.75706
14   FGH 57.26334
15   FGH 10.29247
```